# check point if exists into polygon in google maps

Tags: google-maps

here is my code :

```
var posmark = markerarr["535413"].getPosition();
console.log(posmark);
// **Console.log** ▲
   Ya: 41.64272
   Za: 41.65764999999999
// 

var posshp = poli_arr.s1; 
console.log(posshp);
// **Console.log** ▲
 Zl: yo
 __e3_: Object
 __gm_id: 252
 b: null
 center: P
 fillColor: "#FF0000"
 fillOpacity: 0.35
 gm_accessors_: Object
 map: null
 radius: 100
 strokeColor: "#FF0000"
 strokeOpacity: 0.8
 strokeWeight: 2
 __proto__: c
//

 var res = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(posmark, posshp);
 console.log(res);
//**Console.log** ▲
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getLength' of undefined

//
```

where is broblem? i cant fix it...  i want check marker if exist in polygon zone. if anybody knows better way for checking markers into poligon radius please replay me how i can do this better. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple way for this is this code its tested and works fine :

```
 function API_CONT_UPD(){
    //geting marker objects
    for (element in markerarr){
    //geting marker positions
    var pos = markerarr[element].getPosition();
    //geting shape objects
    for (element2 in poli_arr){
    //check position if is into shape
    if(poli_arr[element2].getBounds().contains(pos) == true){
    var unit = wialon.core.Session.getInstance().getItem(element);
    console.log(unit.getName());

    } //if close

}//shape for statment


} //marker for statment

}//function close
```

Answer (score 0):

The [google.maps.geometry.poly](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly) library only works on [Polygons](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polygon), not [Circles](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Circle).

Although you certainly didn't provide enough information in your question to answer it.

To check if a point in inside a circle use [distanceBetween](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Distance), if the distance between the point and the center of the circle is less than or equal to the radius of the circle, the point is in the circle.

Comment: Note that the bounds will always be a rectangle so some areas (the corners of the bounds around a circle) will not return the correct answer.